# How can I get the list of all actions of ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I tried to use this code, but it does not work (return empty list)

```
var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller);
ActionDescriptor[] actions = controllerDescriptor.GetCanonicalActions();
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked out how to get the ApiController method signatures instead of  Controller.

```
        string Items = "";
        IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();

        foreach (Assembly FoundAssembly in Assemblies)
        {
            string AssemblyName = FoundAssembly.FullName;
            IEnumerable<TypeInfo> Types = FoundAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => type != null && type.IsPublic && type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(type));
            foreach (TypeInfo ControllerType in Types)
            {
                System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector ApiControllerSelection = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector();
                System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor ApiDescriptor = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor(new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration(), ControllerType.Name, ControllerType);
                ILookup<string, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor> ApiMappings = ApiControllerSelection.GetActionMapping(ApiDescriptor);

                foreach (var Maps in ApiMappings)
                {
                    foreach (System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor Actions in Maps)
                    {
                        Items += "[ controller=" + ControllerType.Name + " action=" + ((System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)(Actions)).MethodInfo + "]";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
[ controller=CarController action=System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Login()]
[ controller=CarController action=Void MyCustomGet()]
[ controller=CarController action=Void MyCustomPost()]
[ controller=GenericControllerApi action=System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Login()]
[ controller=ValuesController action=System.String Get()]
[ controller=ValuesController action=System.String Get(Int32)]
[ controller=ValuesController action=Void Post(System.String)]
[ controller=ValuesController action=Void Put(Int32, System.String)]
[ controller=ValuesController action=Void Delete(Int32)]
[ controller=ODataMetadataController action=Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel GetMetadata()]
[ controller=ODataMetadataController action=Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWorkspace GetServiceDocument()]
```

There is an extra controller "ODataMetadataController" that I did not create.  Possibly added by the initial project creation.  I also have not looked to see if this could be simplified.

Comment: I get all apiControllers from assembly and after try get actions from current type (apiController) in foreach

`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Where(type =>
                type != null &&
                type.IsPublic &&
                type.IsClass &&
                !type.IsAbstract &&
                typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(type)`

Comment: `foreach (var controller in GetControllers())
    var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller);`

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to this problem - in my case I suspect it doesn't work because the ReflectedControllerDescriptor is from the .Net MVC library, while the ApiController is from the newer (& separate) Web API library.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  Switching typeof(ApiController) to typeof(Controller) to get the MVC controllers will fill out the action names.